# Is it possible to display a video in a web page directly from a binary buffer?

Tags: javascript, html, video, binary, buffer

Is it possible to display a video directly from consuming a binary buffer without converting to a base64 string first in js&html? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display a video on a web page directly from a binary buffer using the HTML5  element and a data URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video from Binary Buffer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video controls id="videoPlayer" width="640" height="360">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

  <script>
    // Assuming you have your binary buffer in the 'binaryBuffer' variable
    const binaryBuffer = /* ... */; // Your binary buffer here

    // Create a Blob from the binary buffer
    const blob = new Blob([binaryBuffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }); // Adjust the 'type' according to your video format

    // Create a data URL from the Blob
    const dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Get the video element and set the data URL as the source
    const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    videoPlayer.src = dataURL;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example creates a  element with the **controls** attribute for playback control, and it sets the source of the video to the data URL generated from the binary buffer. When the page loads, the video will be displayed, and users can play it using the browser's native video player controls. However, it's essential to consider the performance impact when working with large video files. For large videos, streaming or using a backend server may be more suitable.

Comment: **(1)** I'm not downvoting yet, but this looks like ChatGPT code and **the text is definitely ChatGPT** where 90% is extra stuff that nobody asked about... **(2)** Why are you not telling the Asker to also do a `videoPlayer.load();` after setting source? Why not recommend also setting a `mute` and a `autoplay` option in order to see an immediate response (moving picture) if the code works okay? **(3)** Why would _"using a backend server"_ be more suitable for displaying contents of a blob? RAM can hold large files actually and even if this needed server-side storage then blob is now irrelevant